# Using getchar in C

Tags: c

In the following function:

```
int main() {

    int c;

    c=getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }

}
```

The first time it runs `getchar()` it "waits" for me to enter in text. But the next time (after I've entered in text), it prints the text previously entered. Does `getchar()` work differently depending on whether there's been a previous input, or how exactly does that item work?

If someone could explain what's going on in the above while look that would be great.

Comment: It prints the text due to the `putchar(c)`, skip this line if you dont want the echo

Comment: Yes, `getchar` uses previously entered text if there is any. When you enter a line, the characters in it, including a new-line character, are stored in a buffer. `getchar` is part of a system, actually multiple pieces of software (C, operating system, terminal emulator, other stuff) working together, and it will get characters in the buffer before it waits for you to enter more in the terminal window.

Comment: `stdin` is a input stream.   The C program does not 'see' anything until the 'terminal' handler passes the `stdin` input buffer to the program.  Unless the terminal handler options are modified, the terminal handler will not pass anything to the C program until it sees a newline (typically '\r' or 'n' or EOF)  That is known as `line buffering`.  The terminal handler can be commanded to not echo, run in 'raw' mode (not buffered), etc. Varying the terminal mode via: `#include <termios.h>
  struct termios myTermios;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &myTermios); tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, myTermios );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar()` reads from the "standard input" stream.  By default, it is usual for this stream to be line-buffered, which means that no input is delivered until a complete line is available.

So, when you run your program, it stops at the first `getchar()` until you enter a complete line.  It then runs around the loop, with `getchar()` immediately returning each subsequent character in that line up to and including the terminating newline.  The next `getchar()` after that will then block again, waiting for another line.

Comment: "By default" is unclear.  Certainly line buffering is common for `stdin`, yet not by _default_.

Comment: @chux: Here *"By default"* means *"unless the program has requested a specific buffering mode with `setvbuf()`"*.

Comment: caf, I do not find anything in the C spec that supports the idea "default: line-buffered".  Best I see the _default_ is implementation defined - which does meet the idea of "usual" in the answer as "line-buffered".

Comment: @chux: Exactly so.  The buffering mode if you haven't specifically set one is up to the implementation, but the usual case (across commonly encountered implementations) is to be line-buffered.

Answer (score 0):

since `getchar()` reads a single character from a buffer, even if you enter new input it will keep reading the old buffered input until it runs out of characters.

If you want to be able to input multiple characters but only read the first character of different inputs, then you have to clear the input buffer before the next `getchar()` read.